# Extend line to edge of screen

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, geometry

I have a bounding box at (0, 0, w, h) and a point (x, y) somewhere within that, as well as a directional vector (dx, dy) pointing in some random direction, what I am trying to do is create a line from that point, in that direction to the edge of the bounding box.

Looking at the image below, the black dot is the point, the arrow is the directional vector and the red line is the resulting line I want.

What I am doing now is to simply extend the line by the vector times some random big number that is guaranteed to place it outside the box and then using a line clipping algorithm to clip it. And this totally works, but it feels like a very hacky solution, is there a better way to do this?

[image: Example]

Comment: If the pox is axis aligned, the you can check the sign of dx, dy (to see which sides can potentially be intersected) then check which is smallest between (s1.x - x) / dx, and (s2.y - y) / dy.

Comment: I needed exactly the same for a javascript project a year ago. If you're interested, you can look at the [code here](http://i11www.iti.uni-karlsruhe.de/~algogeo14/team4/polygon.js), see function `intersectScreenEdge` (scroll down to the comment block saying "MATH"). Note that this function can place the point outside of the box with a given distance (parameter `o`) so you are safe when drawing with round caps for example. Simply set `o = 0` if you don't need it, or ignore `o` in the code.

Comment: I find your solution not very hacky as long as you can guarantee that the "random big number" is always big enough to hit an edge (and never too large to introduce a floating point precision problem, or maybe other unexpected problems). You can simply set the length to `w + h` to be safe ([triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality); you could get closer with the diagonal's length but that requires a square root which is unnecessarily slow). (Assuming you're multiplying this with a *normalized* `dx, dy` vector.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, how to find the intersecting point with a vertical line.

Let (x0,y0) be the point inside the box, and (dx,dy) its slope. And say you are trying to find intersection with vertical line y=b.

x0+tdx and y0+tdy are points on the line. So the line intersects the vertical line at y1 such that y1=y0+tdy=b (t>=0). So solve for t (t=(b-y0)/dy) and use the same t to get x1 = x0 + tdx.

Similarly you can also find intersecting point with a horizontal line.

You should find the four points where the line intersects two edges. In most cases two of them will have negative t, discard them. Of the other, pick the one with lowest t and thats your answer.

Further optimization:

Based on the sign of dx and dy, the line could intersect one of the two edges. Eg if both are positive, then it might intersect either top or right side and so on. You can calculate t for only those two edges and pick the one with lowest t.

Comment: This seems like it should work, I'll give it a try when I get home!